# How to create a WMI filter in a GPO via C#

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm trying to create a GPO programatically using the GPMC COM object via C# code. I can create the GPO, but I'm having trouble "inserting" a WMI filter with the GPO. Does anyone know how I can create/update WMI filters for GPOs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the sample code:

```
GPMGMTLib.GPM gPM = new GPMGMTLib.GPM(); 
GPMConstants gPMConstants = gPM.GetConstants(); 
GPMDomain gPMDomain = gPM.GetDomain(domainName, DC, gPMConstants.UseAnyDC); 
GPMGPO obj = gPMDomain.CreateGPO(); 
obj.DisplayName = "New GPO";


//replace with the appropiate GUID
var strWMIFilterID = "{D715559A-7965-45A6-864D-AEBDD9934415}";
var sWMIFilter = string.Format("MSFT_SomFilter.Domain=\"{0}\",ID=\"{1}\"", domainName, strWMIFilterID);

var oWMIFilter = gPMDomain.GetWMIFilter(sWMIFilter); 
obj.SetWMIFilter(oWMIFilter);
```

**Here are some links with additional information:**
[WMIFilters](http://grouppolicy.editme.com/WMIFilters)
[Active Directory Cookbook](http://searchwinit.techtarget.com/searchWin2000/downloads/adcookbook_ch09.pdf)

Comment: Yes, I've seen the WMI GPO Filtering Documentation, That's not what I'm trying to do...
GPMGMTLib.GPM gPM = new GPMGMTLib.GPM();
GPMConstants gPMConstants = gPM.GetConstants();
GPMDomain gPMDomain = gPM.GetDomain(domainName, DC, gPMConstants.UseAnyDC);
GPMGPO obj = gPMDomain.CreateGPO();
obj.DisplayName = "New GPO";

This is where I want to Add a WMI filter to the GPO. C# and GPO documentation is scarce... That is why I am asking here...

Comment: Also,
var oWMIFilter = gPMDomain.GetWMIFilter("FilterName");
obj.SetWMIFilter(oWMIFilter);
would be the next step to add the WMI filter to the GPO. I missing the part that creates it...

Comment: I updated the post to incorporate your code and the syntax for getting the filter. Hope this helps.